# try/catch in TransactionScope in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, transactionscope

I'm using transaction in my c# code. In TransactionScope I log almost everything to make sure everything is done in testing. But if something happens in transaction and it goes to catch my log class doesn't write anything. In localhost I change TransactionScopeOption to "**Suppress**" because database is not in my server. When I'm debugging everything is ok, I can write to log file.But when I change to "**Required**" if it gave an error, it canceled everything as usual but it also can't write first log.
How can I fix this?

My code sample:

```
TransactionOptions tr = new TransactionOptions();
tr.IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.Serializable;
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, tr, System.Transactions.EnterpriseServicesInteropOption.Automatic))//System.TimeSpan.MaxValue))
{
    bool status = false;
    // this log must be written anyway but it won't when it gives an error.
    LogProcess log = new LogProcess(Ssession["DBNAME"], new Guid(), "Transaction begun.");
    try
    {
        // process 1
        // process 2
        .
        .
        .
        if(status)
        {
            LogProcess log1 = new LogProcess(Ssession["DBNAME"], new Guid(), "Transaction will complete soon.");
            scope.Complete();
            LogProcess log1 = new LogProcess(Ssession["DBNAME"], new Guid(), "Transaction completed.");
        }
        else
        {
            LogProcess log2 = new LogProcess(Ssession["DBNAME"], new Guid(), "Transaction will dispose.");
            scope.Dispose();
            LogProcess log2 = new LogProcess(Ssession["DBNAME"], new Guid(), "Transaction disposed.");
        }

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        LogProcess log1 = new LogProcess(Ssession["DBNAME"], new Guid(), "Transaction exception. Error: " + ex.Message);
        scope.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the log written to the database as well? If yes, then that's your problem. When there is an error the log is being rolled back too. You need to wrap the log into another transaction or log to somewhere else like a text file.

Comment: @tucaz Thanks, you are right. But even everything is ok after scope.Complete() it also cannot write to log.

Comment: It sounds like an issue with logging. What is "LogProcess"? I am unfamiliar with it. Is it working elsewhere in your application?

Comment: Most log providers "batch" log writing to DB for performance reasons, if you wait until a certain number of log requests are made then you'll see them all together.

Comment: Also i'm worried about the manual scope.Dispose() within a using statement. You don't need it coz it will be disposed as soon as it leaves the "using" scope.

Comment: It's my log class. I'm using it. But just before scope.Complete() it's writing, after scope.Complete() it's not.

Comment: @TamimSalem, thanks for reply, but think about that. I have 2 table and they are related. I changed something on second one and it affects to first one. And if when I get second table as a datatable and if it's null or whatever it will not give me an error. So transaction will be completed anyway. So I have to dispose manually right?

Comment: Well your catch block will catch the exception, then your application will continue normally, reaching the end of the "using" block and then disposing. no problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I find the structure of your code sample quite confusing. When using a TransactionScope, you typically don't write statements after scope.Complete() or scope.Dispose() have been called. Moreover, the using statement disposes the scope for you, so  IMHO you should not call scope.Dispose() explicitly if you can help it. In other words: try to refactor your code so that it looks something like this:

```
private void PerformTransactionalOperation()
{
    Log.Write("Starting operation.");        

    try
    {
        using (var scope = CreateTransactionScope())
        {
            if (PerformTransactionalOperationCore())
            {
                Log.Write("Committing...");
                scope.Complete();
                Log.Write("Committed");
            }
            else
            {
                Log.Write("Operation aborted.");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Log.Write("Operation failed: " + exception.Message);
        throw;
    }
}

private bool PerformTransactionalOperationCore()
{
    // Perform operations and return status...
}
```

Secondly, the transaction-scope was specifically designed to complete only when no exception was raised, so your design might be improved by letting the PerformTransactionalOperationCore throw a specific exception instead of returning **false**.

Then on the logging matter: make sure your logging framework does not participate in the same transaction as the operation your are logging about. You can do this by always logging within a TransactionScope with option **Suppress** (that is, when you are logging to a resource that is transaction-aware in the first place, like a database). And by the way, why are you writing log-statements by instantiating new LogProcess-instances?

Comment: I'm gonna try it. Thank you. My log class normally very wide. My customer wants to see almost everything. That one was just an example for testing.

Comment: I understand your requirement to put in a lot of log-statements if your client demands it, I was just curious why you have chosen to implement it the way you did: it's not very conventional to instantiate a new object each time you need to log something (assuming the LogProcess-contructor performs the actual write).